# Problema librería kableExtra y símbolos math RMarkdown

Tags: r, rstudio, r-markdown

estoy presentando un problema en los archivos .rmd que realizo. Cada vez que pongo la librería `kableExtra` se pierde la nomenclatura matemáticas de las tablas creadas con `knitr::kable`. 
Estos los códigos que estoy utilizando.

````
    ---
    title: "..."
    date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%A, %B %d, %Y')`"
    output:
      pdf_document: 
        keep_tex: yes
        toc: yes
      html_document: 
        keep_md: true
        toc: yes
        toc_float: true
        code_folding: hide
      keep_tex: yes
      word_document: default
      fig_cap: yes
    header-includes:
    - \usepackage{float}
    - \floatplacement{figure}{H}
    ---

    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    # define knitr options
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(warning = FALSE)
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE)
    knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, fig.pos= "h")
    ```

    ```{r, include=FALSE}
    options(tinytex.verbose = TRUE)
    ```

    ```{r, include=FALSE}

    # instalar paquetes. 
    library(tidyverse)
    library(knitr)
    library(ggthemes)
    library(GGally)
    library(lmtest)##paquete para validación de estimadores de errores. 
    library(leaps)##paquete para selección de modelos a través de estadisticos BIC, CP, R2adj

    ```{r creación de tabla de variables a utilizar, echo = FALSE}
    vardadas <- c('$y$', '$x_1$', '$x_2$', '$x_3$', '$x_4$', '$x_5$', '$x_6$', '$x_7$', '$x_8$', '$x_9$')
    def_var <- c('Precio de venta de la casa',
                 'Impuestos (local, escuela, condado)', 
                 'Número de baños',
                 'Tamaño de lote',
                 'Espacio vital', 
                 'Número de puestos de garaje',
                 'Número de habitaciones', 
                 'Número de dormitorios', 
                 'Edad del hogar', 
                 'Cantidad de chimeneas')
    unidad <- c('x/1000', 'x/1000', 'n°', '$ft^2$', '$ft^2$', 'n°', 'n°', 'n°', 
                'Años', 'n°')

    tip_var <- c('v. respuesta', 'v. regresora', 'v. regresora', 'v. regresora', 'v. regresora',
                 'v. regresora', 'v. regresora', 'v. regresora', 'v. regresora', 'v. regresora')
    dbnamescol <- c('precioventa', 'impuestos', 'num_banos', 'tamano_lote', 'espac_vital',
                    'num_puestos_gar', 'num_hab', 'num_dorm', 'edad_hogar', 'cant_chimen')

    names_df <- c('Variables dadas', 'Definición', 'Tipo de variable (en modelo)',
                  'Nombre de variable (en db)', 'Unidad')
    df_modelo <- data.frame(vardadas, def_var, tip_var, dbnamescol, unidad)
    colnames(df_modelo) <- names_df

    knitr::kable(df_modelo,
                 caption="Organizac[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]ión de las variables", 
                 align = 'c') 
    ```
````

De este código obtengo lo siguiente:

[image: Esta es la tabla resultante del código anterior sin la librería <code>KableExtra</code>]

Al adicionar la librería `KableExtra` se pierden los simbolos matematicos:

````
    ```{r, include=FALSE}

    # instalar paquetes. 
    library(tidyverse)
    library(kableExtra)
    library(knitr)
    library(ggthemes)
    library(GGally)
    library(lmtest)##paquete para validación de estimadores de errores. 
    library(leaps)##paquete para selección de modelos a través de estadisticos BIC, CP, R2adj
    ```
````

[image: Esta es la tabla resultante cuando se adiciona como librería <code>KableExtra</code>]

Cuando utilizo el argumento `escape=F` resulta un error donde no se reconocen los simbolos. 
Requiero usar esta `KableExtra` para modificar el tamaño de la tabla y adicionar notas al pie de página. 
Agradecería mucho su ayuda.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bienvenido/a ggropius,

pude lograr una tabla con los símbolos correctos forzando a `kable` a sacar el output en MarkDown, de modo que Pandoc se encargue de transformarla en lugar de pasar la tabla en LaTeX crudo.

```
kable(df_modelo, 
      format = "markdown",   #Pasa una tabla en md que pandoc formatea a LaTeX
      caption="Organizac[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]ión de las variables", 
         align = 'c')
```

No sé si es una solución completa, porque si vas a utilizar `kableExtra` para seguir formateando la tabla después no va a funcionar con md como input. Pero para este problema sirve.

Suerte!

Comment: Hola mpaladino, intenté lo que me comentas y funcionó bien, sin embargo,  definitivamente necesito seguir usan KableExtra para introducir las notas a la tabla. Intenté con pandoc.table pero no quedan como con KableExtra.

Comment: Da muchísimo trabajo hacer tablas complejas en LaTeX desde R. Siempre termino en lo mismo, o simplificando mucho la tabla (sin notas, sin multicolumnas, etc) o editándola directamente en el source de LaTeX. Suerte!